# How to compile subfiles with custom fonts applied in main.tex

Tags: fonts, subfiles

I have structure of the project like..

```
\documentclass[a4,twoside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{subfiles} 
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[AutoFakeBold=0.5, AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{AdaniRegular.ttf} % font loaded in project

\begin{document}

\chapter{LV network planning }
\subfile{Sections/LVnetwork.tex}


\chapter{Service network planning}\label{Ch1}
\subfile{Sections/ServiceNetwork.tex}

\end{document}
```

I am unable to compile individual subfile in Adani font. I am using overleaf

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You are using XeLaTeX, right? You should mention such things in our posts because it influences the solutions.

Comment: you should show a small sample LVnetwork.tex and ServiceNetwork.tex to show the problem No one can test your example currently so it does not help answer the question. Why do you need subfiles at all here rather than just use `\input` ?